# php mail() cannot connect, but telnet works

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail, telnet

I am trying to use the php mail() function. I am using a remote mail server w/ port 25, which I can telnet to and it connects just fine. I have configured my php.ini with these settings and have also tried ini_set(), but I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at xxx.xx.xx.xxx; port 25, verify your "SMTP"; and "smtp_port"; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\....php on line 23
```

Any help is very appreciated! I am using Windows Server 2008, Apache 2.2, and PHP 5.2.17

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, PHP's built-in mail function has some issues with SMTP authentication. Maybe you want to try PEAR mail package or other mailers.

Answer (score 1):

Only [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) helped me. mail() didn't work with

```
smtp: mail.*******.com
port: 2525
auth: off
```

while `telent mail.*******.com 2525` worked and did send emails